# Magento 2 Add Custom attribute value on customer order graphql

Tags: magento2, sales-order, graphql, extrafee

- I have created two extensions and it's an add fee on Order Total.
  Now on adding this fee to Get CustomerOrder Graphql so, we override the default Magento Get CustomerOrder Graphql and it's working.
- But We Enabled both fee extensions and ran Graphql then only one fee show and not showing both extension fee on Get CustomerOrder Graphql.

Below is the Query.

```
query{  
  customerOrders {  
   items {  
      order_number  
      id  
      created_at  
      grand_total  
      status  
      fee1  
      fee2  
    }  
  }  
}
```

when I execute the above query, it will display fee1 but it will not display fee2.  If I disable the fee1 extension then fee2 displays on graphql.

Response:

```
{
    "data": {  
        "customerOrders": {  
            "items": [  
                {  
                    "order_number": "000000004",  
                    "id": "4",  
                    "created_at": "2023-12-05 11:58:52",  
                    "grand_total": 146,  
                    "status": "pending",  
                    "fee1": 25,  
                    "fee2": null,  
                }  
            ]  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**Fee1 Code is here**
GraphQL queries File  **`etc/schema.graphqls`**

```
type Query {  customerOrders: CustomerOrders @resolver(class: "Vendor\\Extension\\Model\\Resolver\\Orders") @deprecated(reason: "Use the `customer` query instead.")  }  
type CustomerOrders @doc(description: "The collection of orders that match the conditions defined in the filter.") {   items: [CustomerOrder]! @doc(description: "An array of customer orders.")  page_info: SearchResultPageInfo @doc(description: "Contains pagination metadata.")   total_count: Int @doc(description: "The total count of customer orders.")  }  
type CustomerOrder  {  fee1: Float   }
```

GraphQL Resolver File  **`Model/Resolver/Orders.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactoryInterface;
/**
 * Orders data reslover
 */
class Orders implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactoryInterface
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactoryInterface $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactoryInterface $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {

         


        /** @var ContextInterface $context */
        if (false === $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getIsCustomer()) {
            throw new GraphQlAuthorizationException(__('The current customer isn\'t authorized.'));
        }

        $items = [];
        $orders = $this->collectionFactory->create($context->getUserId());



        /** @var Order $order */
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $items[] = [
                'id' => $order->getId(),
                'fee1' => $order->getFee(), 
                'model' => $order
            ];
        }
        
        return ['items' => $items];
    }
}
```

**Fee2 Code is here**
GraphQL queries File  **`etc/schema.graphqls`**

```
type Query {  customerOrders: CustomerOrders @resolver(class: "Vendor\\Extension\\Model\\Resolver\\Orders") @deprecated(reason: "Use the `customer` query instead.")  }  
type CustomerOrders @doc(description: "The collection of orders that match the conditions defined in the filter.") {   items: [CustomerOrder]! @doc(description: "An array of customer orders.")  page_info: SearchResultPageInfo @doc(description: "Contains pagination metadata.")   total_count: Int @doc(description: "The total count of customer orders.")  }  
type CustomerOrder  {  fee2: Float   }
```

GraphQL Resolver File  **`Model/Resolver/Orders.php`**

```
 <?php
    namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Resolver;
    
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
    use Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextInterface;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactoryInterface;
    /**
     * Orders data reslover
     */
    class Orders implements ResolverInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var CollectionFactoryInterface
         */
        private $collectionFactory;
    
        /**
         * @param CollectionFactoryInterface $collectionFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            CollectionFactoryInterface $collectionFactory
        ) {
            $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        }
    
        /**
         * @inheritDoc
         */
        public function resolve(
            Field $field,
            $context,
            ResolveInfo $info,
            array $value = null,
            array $args = null
        ) {
    
             
    
    
            /** @var ContextInterface $context */
            if (false === $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getIsCustomer()) {
                throw new GraphQlAuthorizationException(__('The current customer isn\'t authorized.'));
            }
    
            $items = [];
            $orders = $this->collectionFactory->create($context->getUserId());
    
    
    
            /** @var Order $order */
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                $items[] = [
                    'id' => $order->getId(),
                    'fee2' => $order->getCustomFee(), 
                    'model' => $order
                ];
            }
            
            return ['items' => $items];
        }
    }
```

**Also fee1 & fee2 value Available on sales_order table**.

Comment: Please share your code here. I think something is conflicting with the same class or method.

Comment: @Msquare Please check above code

Comment: Thanks, Also please share your fee2 source code

Comment: @Msquare  Yes, i have attached fee2 source code

Comment: @KevalChauhan you have created the two different modules for fee1 & fee2 ?

Comment: Yes, I have created two modules.